# Json returns null value

Tags: php, json, curl, file-get-contents

I want to get Json data from Carquery API. But none of my code worked.

First i tried to get the data using curl. This is my code

```
    $loginUrl = 'http://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?callback=?&cmd=getTrims&year=2015';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$loginUrl);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    var_dump(json_decode($result));
```

It returned null. And then i tried using file_get_content. This is my code :

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?callback=?&cmd=getTrims&year=2015');
$obj = json_decode($json);
var_dump($obj);
```

Unfortunately it didn't work either.

Any help please?

Comment: Can you post your json string looks like it's an invalid json. Try using http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your json string.

Comment: After looking at your site it shows a ?( before the json string. Remove these 2 characters.

Comment: @StijnBernards That's essential for JSONP. You need to remove your JSONP callback from the URL as PHP doesn't need it, nor can it use it. `/?cmd=getTrims&year=2015`

Comment: @BenFortune Today I learned. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json data return from that API is not correct, i tried using [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) to check it.

If the callback part is removed from

> 'http://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?callback=?&cmd=getTrims&year=2015';

into

> 'http://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?cmd=getTrims&year=2015';

it will produce right json and can be parsed either using file_get_content() or curl.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try this:

```
    $loginUrl = 'http://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?callback=?&cmd=getTrims&year=2015';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$loginUrl);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
if($result === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    var_dump(json_decode($result));
}
    curl_close($ch);
```

so you can see error if any on curl request.

and 2nd thing that url:
`'http://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?callback=?&cmd=getTrims&year=2015'`

are you sure that the must be 2 (two) `?` (question marks) ?